# invoke action via icon not working

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Im using the following code which I want to invoke the edit action when you click on the image
currently i got error

```
<a href="@Url.Action("  ", "Edit", new { id = item.UserId })"><img src="../../imges/pen.jpg"></a>
```

This is the error

```
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Edit/ /f
```

when I use the following defult code its works,how should I invoke the edit action from the icon?

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.UserId }, new { @class = "btn btn-mini btn-info icon-edit bigger-120" }) |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", new { id = item.UserId })">
   <img src="../../imges/pen.jpg">
</a>
```

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460294%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) the first parameter of `@Url.Action()` is the `actionName`, the second the additional parameters.

Comment: Thanks ,I try it and its not working,I check the ralitve URL and when I use the default button its http://localhost:58472/User/Edit/fg but when I use the icon its http://localhost:58472/Edit/Edit/fg any idea how to change it?

Comment: I've change it to  <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "User" and its works thanks!